# Javascript call method in another method

Tags: javascript, methods

Now I'm trying to implement Unity Webgl with jslib. I'm so confused about how to call method in another method's function. I want to call method Recv when message was coming (ws.onmessage). But, it show "TypeError: this.Recv is undefined". Could you please help me figure out this source? 
Thank you !!!!!

Here's my source code

```
var ws = null;
var init_url = "";
var received_msg = "";
var error_msg = "";

var WebsocketLib = {
Hello: function(){
    window.alert("Hello,world!");
},
InitSocket: function(url){
    init_url = Pointer_stringify(url);
    console.log("InitWebSocket: "+init_url);
    ws = new WebSocket(init_url);
    ws.onopen = function(evt){ 
            console.log("Connect");
            isConnected = false;
            ws.send("hello");
        }; 
    ws.onclose = function(evt) { 
            console.log("Close");
            isConnected = false;
        }; 
    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
            received_msg = evt.data;
            console.log("[recv] "+received_msg);
            this.Recv.call(this);
        }; 
    ws.onerror = function(evt) {
            error_msg = evt.data;
            console.log("[error] "+error_msg);
            this.Error.call(this);
        };
},
Recv: function(){
    console.log("[recv] "+received_msg);
    var buffer = _malloc(received_msg.length + 1);
    writeStringToMemory(returnStr, buffer);
    return buffer;
},
Error: function(){
    console.log("[error] "+error_msg);
    var buffer = _malloc(error_msg.length + 1);
    writeStringToMemory(error_msg, buffer);
    return buffer;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside of ws.onmessage `this` will refer to `ws` (as we're inside a method of ws) and not `WebsocketLib`.

However, inside Initsocket, where you define the handlers, `this` would correctly (*in the sense that this is what you want*) refer to the WebsocketLib object, so you can create a bound function to bind the *outer* `this` value to be used as `this` inside the event handler, like this:

```
ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
        received_msg = evt.data;
        console.log("[recv] "+received_msg);
        this.Recv.call(this);
}.bind(this);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's really clear and easy to understand.

Answer (score 2):

in JavaScript the value of `this` behaves differently than in other languages. Its value depends on how the function is called. You can read more about it in the [Mozilla MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

To solve your specific problem you can:

```
InitSocket: function(url){
    var that = this;                                  // [1]
    init_url = Pointer_stringify(url);
    console.log("InitWebSocket: "+init_url);
    ws = new WebSocket(init_url);
    ws.onopen = function(evt){ 
            console.log("Connect");
            isConnected = false;
            ws.send("hello");
        }; 
    ws.onclose = function(evt) { 
            console.log("Close");
            isConnected = false;
        }; 
    ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
            received_msg = evt.data;
            console.log("[recv] "+received_msg);
            that.Recv.call(that);                     // [2]
        }; 
    ws.onerror = function(evt) {
            error_msg = evt.data;
            console.log("[error] "+error_msg);
            that.Error.call(that);                    // [2]
        };
},
```

In line 1 I bind the `this` variable to a custom variable that I decided to call `that` (but you can call it as you want). Then in line 2 I used `that` instead of `this`.

Inside the `ws.onmessage` function the value of `this` is not referring to the instance of `WebsocketLib`, so you need to use this "trick" and access the right `this` value using the one saved in the closure, inside the value of `that`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: I am a learner. So I suppose that `this.Error.call(this)` won't work neither, right?

Comment: Yes, for the same reason `this.Error.call(this)` does not work, you have to change `this` to `that`. For a better understanding of `this` you can read the MDN article I suggested and [this StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3127440/2009013).

Comment: Just edited my answer to correct "this.Error.call(this)" to "that.Error.call(that)" and "that.Recv.call(this);" to "that.Recv.call(that);". You need to change the `this` inside the "call(this)" for the same reason I explained. Otherwise, the "Recv" and "Error" function calls will not be bind to the correct object instance.